# Mobile Safari: "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost."

Tags: webpack, safari, mobile-safari, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to work on my Webpack-compiled React webapp on Mobile Safari. When I serve the bundle with webpack-dev-server without compression, I get this error

> "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost."

basically every time. But, when I run webpack-dev-server with `--compress`, I see this error a lot less frequently. Without compression the bundle is 6.7mb. With compression it's much smaller: 1.5mb. So there seems to be some kind of timeout in Mobile Safari that causes the bundle load to fail at some size.

I am wondering:

- Whether anyone else has experienced this
- Whether my assessment of the problem is correct
- What other steps might be taken to mitigate this problem

Developing for Mobile Safari is already pretty unpleasant for me, so I'd like to optimize the change/reload cycle with Mobile Safari.

Comment: same issue. Have no idea